# Ruby/Rails db connection pool implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a ruby on rails application that takes a user http request, connects to the database, and sends back the response. To make the application faster, I would like to implement the db connection pool to avoid creating a new connection every time. I tried looking into the connection pool library, but did not fully grasp how to use it. Any help or pointers would be highly appreciated? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your database.yml file? You can just have `pool: number indicating size of connection pool (default 5)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I saw that too, and increased it to 25. But, I noticed those to be exhausted also. Is it just specifying the connection pool sufficient or my code needs some logic to setup and tear down them too.

Comment: That sounds like you might not be releasing used connections properly

Comment: That could be the case. Could you please suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord is the default ORM library that Rails uses and it automatically handles connection pooling for you so unless your using some other library you don't need to do anything.

Some of the pool options are configurable if you feel like you need to mess with them but I doubt you would http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html